# how to remove the id before the file name using php

Tags: php

For this code: 
 `$file1='Package_document/3899_In Detail_Search_page_4584.docx'`

I tried this code, but it not working.
`$pattern = preg_replace('/^[0-9_]+/','',$file1);`

i need to remove  this thing 3899_
How to remove ? Please help to find the answer

Comment: Try `/[0-9]+_/`

Comment: Might be simpler if you fixed/modified the source that created the what seems to be a dynamically-generated number in the first place, so you wouldn't have to do that each time, should this be the case.

Comment: @modsfabio Thanks its working

Answer (score 0):

This will remove text between symbols / and _. / will be left and _ will be removed

```
preg_replace('~(/).*?(_)~', '$1', $file1);
```

Output will be: Package_document/In Detail_Search_page_4584.docx